# Поле в виде массива из значений поля другой таблицы

Tags: массивы, mysql

Как можно в MySQL реализовать такую связь между двумя таблицами:

- в записях из таблицы `А` хранятся уникальные числовые id = 3, 8, 67, 75, 100
- в `B` есть поле `list`, которое может хранить значения только из поля `id` таблицы `А`, причём  одновременно их может быть несколько, например `list=(3,67,8)`

Comment: так а связываете то что ? обычно хранят так

   A: id,value
   B: id(если оно вообще надо),A_ID

Comment: Может [это][1] подойдет? Хотя я не сторонник таких методов. Лучше ввести таблицу с отошением один-ко-многим


  [1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Comment: скорее всего надо один-ко многим и потом при запросе PIVOT делать

Comment: Если вы души не чаете от хранения в качестве массива, можно преобразовывать массив в Json объект и заносить в таблицу Б как строку. Это часто используется на практике. А обработку таких данных - возлагайте на PHP, во избежание сложных запросов, хотя можно и поспорить тут. Но в вашем случае - рекомендую.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно так не поступают, денормализуя данные таким образом, вы теряете все преимущества СУБД: скорость обработки, богатый и гибкий язык манипуляции множествами. При этом сохраняете все недостатки: сложный и старый язык запросов SQL, создававшийся во времена, когда время разработчика стоило дешево, а компьютерное - дорого, бедные и непроизводительные возможности манипуляции строками.

Если вы хотите извлечь из MySQL все преимущества, лучше вам лучше нормализовать схему

- в записях из таблицы `А` хранятся уникальные числовые `id = 3, 8, 67,
  75, 100`
- в таблице `B` каждому идентификатору из множества
  `list=(3,67,8)` соответствует отдельная строка

Например

```
1 3
2 67
3 8
```

При такой организации данных, вы получаете возможность обработки при помощи всех механизмов SQL (вложенные запросы, соединения, многочисленные операторы обработки множеств). Если вам не удобно переработать таблицу `B`, заведите промежуточную таблицу `С`, где храните данные в нормализованном виде - поверьте не смотря на кажущуюся дополнительную сложность, это окупится при эксплуатации и поддержке приложения.